# Dynamically generating directories for logs and results

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I'm trying to configure locust to store my log files into a a `logs/` directory. For example:

```
# example.conf
locustfile = example/locust.py
host = http://www.example.com
users = 10
spawn-rate = 10
logfile = logs/example.log
```

However, locust will fail if the `logs/` directory does not exist. I've tried adding the directory with an init event listener:

```
@events.init.add_listener
def on_init(**kw):
    if 'logs' not in os.listdir():
        os.mkdir('logs')
```

But locust fails before it gets to this point. Is there any way around this issue with the current way locust is built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your code in the top/module level of your locust file, not inside a function, and it will be executed before everything else.

```
if 'logs' not in os.listdir():
    os.mkdir('logs')
```